# package Kotlin .kt class in a JAR

Tags: jar, jvm, package, kotlin, manifest

How do I build `HelloWorld.kt` as a `JAR` so that it runs?

```
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ kotlinc HelloWorld.kt --include-runtime -d HelloWorld.jar
error: invalid argument: --include-runtime
info: use -help for more information
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ kotlinc HelloWorld.kt -d HelloWorld.jar
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.text.StringFactory to constructor java.lang.String(char[],boolean)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.text.StringFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ java -jar HelloWorld.jar 
no main manifest attribute, in HelloWorld.jar
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ cat HelloWorld.kt 
import kotlin.jvm.JvmStatic

object HelloWorld {
    @JvmStatic
    public fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Hello, world!" + args[0])
    }
}
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$
```

Note that it's declared as a class, and so the method is not on the top level(?).  Would want to include the `kotlin` runtime as well.

Do I need to manually create a `MANIFEST.MF` with `Main-Class` for the [entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a build tool like Gradle for that task.

In this example, a Jar with Manifest entry is being created: https://github.com/s1monw1/kotlin_vertx_example/blob/master/build.gradle.kts

Comment: does kotlin allow or work with shadowJar?  Is this an odd way to build and package kotlin?  Thanks for the sample build :)      will have to adapt it, then accept.

Comment: Sure you can work with shadowJar, you’ll find examples

Comment: to use shadowJar I narrowed the scoped of the question as: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47121264/262852   and will review your answer.  thanks again :)