# specify Kotlin class as the Main-Class entry point in a MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: gradle, jar, kotlin, uberjar, shadowjar

How do I [explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46980051/262852) tell `shadowJar` to use a Kotlin file as the entry point for the resulting `uberJar`?  (Or, fat `JAR` as you prefer.)

clumsily editing `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and the replacing it in the zip file (used the GUI to put it back):

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ ll
total 900
drwxrwxr-x 2 thufir thufir   4096 Nov  5 03:42 ./
drwxrwxr-x 8 thufir thufir   4096 Nov  5 03:42 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 903184 Nov  5 03:42 kotlinAdder.jar
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ jar xf kotlinAdder.jar 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ ll
total 928
drwxrwxr-x  7 thufir thufir   4096 Nov  5 03:42 ./
drwxrwxr-x  8 thufir thufir   4096 Nov  5 03:42 ../
drwxrwxr-x  2 thufir thufir   4096 Nov  5 03:42 demo/
drwxrwxr-x 17 thufir thufir  12288 Nov  5 03:42 kotlin/
-rw-rw-r--  1 thufir thufir 903184 Nov  5 03:42 kotlinAdder.jar
drwxrwxr-x  3 thufir thufir   4096 Nov  5 03:42 META-INF/
drwxrwxr-x  3 thufir thufir   4096 Nov  5 03:42 net/
drwxrwxr-x  4 thufir thufir   4096 Nov  5 03:42 org/
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ nano META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App

thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ nano META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: demo.MainKt
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$ java -jar kotlinAdder.jar 
Hello, world!
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/build/libs$
```

Success of sorts.  It ran the Kotlin class as intended.

project:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── net
    │   │       └── bounceme
    │   │           └── dur
    │   │               └── kotlin
    │   │                   └── App.java
    │   └── kotlin
    │       └── demo
    │           ├── example.kt
    │           └── main.kt
    └── test
        └── java

13 directories, 9 files
```

build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    //   id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.1.51"
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.1'
}

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
    //publishAlways()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'kotlinAdder'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

//mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App'
mainClassName = 'demo.MainKt'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.51"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'

}
```

How do I tell gradle to keep using `shadowJar` but to build the `MANIFEST.MF` as manually edited, to set `Main-Class: demo.MainKt` explicitly as the entry point.

Else, the Java code [runs by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47118023/262852) **even** when I've explicitly set the entry point as above in the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a typo / not reproducible. I've tried to mimic the project [here](https://github.com/madhead/playgrounds/tree/master/47121264) - `build.gradle` (without build scans) and kotlin sources. Shadow jar has correct `Main-Class` entry in my case. Looks like the OP have another issue.

Comment: Also, as per their docs: "Applying application plugin and settings mainClassName automatically configures the Main-Class attribute in the manifest for shadowJar".

Comment: `java -jar` also works: `./gradlew clean assemble && java -jar build/libs/kotlinAdder.jar` prints `Hello, world!`

Comment: @madhead ok, well, dunno.  works fine.  https://github.com/THUFIR/kotlin  thank you though :)